# opening a file VBA from path data in query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query in my MS ACCESS database that yields:

event (in this case, a goanna has been photographed)
photo name (e.g., IMG_0002.JPG)
path to file (e.g., c:\documents\random_place)

In the form I have built, I added a button, and built this event:

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()

    Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\Documents\random_place\IMG_0002.JPG"

End Sub
```

No problem.

But what I really want is to populate the path to the file with information returned by the query (as opposed to having typed it in manually), since button I have there is static, and now all the events show photo IMG_0002.JPG, where in fact different records have different file names and even paths.

I guess I am looking for something like:

Application.FollowHyperlink paste{result from path},{result from filename}

if you see what I mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the query you mention is the form's RecordSource, code can reference fields/controls to build the file path\name in the button click event.

`FollowHyperlink Me![path to file] & "\" & Me![photo name]`